# Can I get the current executing controller from HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using some 3rd party classes. I want to get the routevalues of my controller in that. Unfortunately it doesn't hand me the current controller that is executing. Can I get it from HttpContext?

The class looks something like:

```
public class ServiceStationVisibilityProvider
        : ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider 
    {

        public bool IsVisible(SiteMapNode node, HttpContext context, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
        {
            node.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //need to access routevalues and set title
            return true;
        }
```

Now I could manully inspect Request.RawUrl and parse and do funky things. However, I don't want to write that kind and fall into trouble later when the application grows.
    }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search the values of `"controller"` and `"action"` in this object

```
HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure in what context you are executing, but you can get it from the RequestContext:

```
RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
```